# iMessage navigation controller bar hidden when expanded

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I'm working on a new iMessage app and am seeing some weird behavior. When I expand the app from compact to expanded the navigation bar disappears. To simulate it create a controller thats embedded in a navigation controller. Have it segue to another controller and in compact it acts normal with a back button. Expand it and the navigation bar is missing. I did the segue with a button tap and doing the flow when everything is expanded still has the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in iMessage. This worked for me

https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/how-to-deal-with-imessage-navigation-bar-covering-top-of-view-bug/